# Rail 4 Devise 3.2 forgot password token is invalid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Whenever I set a new password I got an invalid token error message. I've debug this method in Devise,    reset_password_token = Devise.token_generator.digest(self, :reset_password_token, params[:reset_token]) and the token is indeed different from the one saved in the database. does any one here or know why the token are different?

EDIT: here's the controller code that I use to override Devise::PasswordController

```
class PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController

 def edit
   original_token       = params[:reset_password_token]
   reset_password_token = Devise.token_generator.digest(self, :reset_password_token, original_token)
   self.resource = resource_class.find_or_initialize_with_error_by(:reset_password_token, reset_password_token)
   if !resource.errors.empty?
     flash[:alert] = "Password token is invalid"
     redirect_to new_session_path(resource_name)
   end
  end
end
```

Comment: Please post the controller code where you update your password with the new password.

Comment: @Hoa I've edited my post for the controller code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the following line

```
Devise.token_generator.digest(self, :reset_password_token, original_token)
```

The first parameter should be the model class which acts as your user model. At the moment, you pass the PasswordsController class. If you also name your user model `User` then change that line to

```
Devise.token_generator.digest(User, :reset_password_token, original_token)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check `reset_password_period_valid?`:

```
if resource.reset_password_period_valid?
  set_minimum_password_length
  resource.reset_password_token = params[:reset_password_token]
else
  flash[:alert] = 'Your password reset link has expired, please enter your email to send a new one.'
  redirect_to new_password_path(resource_name)
end
```

An expired token error won't added to the resource unless you attempt to update by token.